# How can I use XSL, but with no toolbar, when using XsltListViewWebPart with a custom view?

Tags: 2010, custom, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have the following XsltListViewWebPart  on a custom application page:

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server"
    Title="My Documents"
    ListUrl="Lists/MyDocuments"
    ViewGuid="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"
    ChromeType="TitleOnly"
    ShowToolbarWithRibbon="FALSE"
    >
    <XmlDefinition>
       <View MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" Level="1">
           <Query>
                <Where>
                    <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='MyDocMyId'/>
                        <Value Type='Text'>{controlMyID}</Value>
                    </Eq>
                </Where>
            </Query>
           <ViewFields>
               <FieldRef Name="DocIcon"/>
               <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
               <FieldRef Name="MyDocType"/>
               <FieldRef Name="MyDocDate"/>
               <FieldRef Name="MyDocNotes"/>
           </ViewFields>
           <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
           <Toolbar Type="FreeForm"/>
       </View>
    </XmlDefinition>
    <parameterbindings>
       <!-- ootb bindings snipped -->
       <ParameterBinding Name="controlMyID" Location="Control(myDocMyId,Value)" DefaultValue="0" />
    </parameterbindings>
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```

It's working great, except it is rendering with the New/Upload/Actions/Settings/View toolbar. If I remove the [ViewGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.basexsltlistwebpart.viewguid.aspx) attribute, the toolbar goes away, but the web part renders using 2007-ish table-based HTML.

Is there a way to configure a XsltListViewWebPart using a custom view so that it has the same XSLT look and feel, but does not show the toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of using Permissions to hide the toolbar. I guess the toolbar is displayed only if the role has "Full Control" and/or "Design". I assume most of your site users will not have these permissions? Removing them should get rid of the toolbar!

Answer (score 0):

Change the `<Toolbar Type="FreeForm"/>` to `<Toolbar Type="None"/>`

Comment: No change. And, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms450295(v=office.12).aspx), the only values are Standard and FreeForm.

Comment: try removing the toolbar attribute entirely.

Comment: No difference there either. My first version didn't have the Toolbar element or the ShowToolbarWithRibbon attribute. Adding them didn't change anything, but I included them in my question for completeness.